# RepeatWhen in combination Observable.of(x) has unexpected behavior

Tags: rxjs5, reactive

I am having unexpected behavior with Observable.of() and repeatWhen. I was wondering if this is correct behavior or not, and why?

```
const value = 5;
let variable = 0;

const getValue = () => {
    variable = variable + 1;
    return value * variable;
}

function test () {
    Observable.of(getValue())
        .repeatWhen(obs => obs.delay(1000))
        .subscribe(value => console.log(value);
}
```

Expected: 5 10 15 20 ...

Result: 5 5 5 5 ...

Apparently, the value returned by Observable.of() is reused for each subsequent subscribe. How, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `getValue()` is evaluated only once and immediately. That's got nothing to do with rxjs, it's just how Javascript works.  You need to evaluate it on each retry instead, which you can do by using `defer`:

```
Observable.defer(() => Observable.of(getValue()))
  .repeatWhen(obs => obs.delay(1000))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with use of `value`. You are changing `variable` not `value`(also the value is available in *two* scopes i.e. *Global* and *closer* scope).

**To solve the issue,** Change the definition of `getValue` as following:

```
const getValue = () => {
    variable = variable + 1;
    value = value * variable;
    return value;
}
```

So, corrected code will look like:

```
const value = 5;
let variable = 0;

const getValue = () => {
    variable = variable + 1;
    value = value * variable;
    return value;
}

function test () {
    Observable.of(getValue())
        .repeatWhen(obs => obs.delay(1000))
        .subscribe(value => console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: @Elias we are printing `variable` not `value`.

Comment: variable will return 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 as you can see what getValue() does.